# Как в фоне отслеживать запущенные приложения?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно, что бы приложение запускалось в фоне и при запуске другого приложения(Например Google Chrome), говорило боту отправить пользователю сообщение. Как управлять ботом я знаю, но не знаю, как собственно отследить запущенные приложения? ОС: Windows. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например:

- Запросить текущий список процессов
- Проверить есть ли в списке процесс с указанным названием
- Если есть, то что-нибудь с ним сделать

Пример с [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) по закрытию процесса калькулятора:

```
import time

# pip install psutil
import psutil

while True:
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        if process.name() == 'calc.exe':
            process.kill()

    # Повтор через 5 секунд
    time.sleep(5)
```

Вместо закрытия процесса добавьте свои действия